# Appending filenames in jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

I have an image on a site which I want to change the filename / source of at specific sizes. I have it kind of working but its buggy - see code below.

This works well if the original filename is example.jpg - however it falls over if the original filename is example@2x.jpg - I am using retinaJS on the site - so when a wide mobile device loads the page it renders the example.jpg file as example@2x.jpg - but then when switched to portrait - the issue happens as the code I have doesnt rename example@2x.jpg to become example_mobile@2x.jpg...

I think I need a 2nd statement in the first section to rename files that end in @2x.jpg to become example_mobile@2x.jpg - currently they are being renamed to example@2x_mobile@2x.jpg which is wrong...

Any ideas? I am stumped!

```
function endsWith(str, suffix) {
return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
}

var clientsLIControl = function() {

var windowSizeClients = $(window).width();


    //if (windowSizeClients <= 480) {
    if (windowSizeClients <= 568) {

     $("div.nivoSlider img").each(function() {
         if (!endsWith($(this).attr('src'), '_mobile@2x.jpg')) {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.jpg/, '') + '_mobile@2x.jpg');
         }

    //call div resizer
    resizeDiv();     

     });

     $("div.heroElementWrapper img").each(function() {
         if (!endsWith($(this).attr('src'), '_mobile@2x.jpg')) {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.jpg/, '') + '_mobile@2x.jpg');
         }

    //call div resizer
    resizeDiv();    

     });

    }

    //else if (windowSizeClients >= 481) {
    else if (windowSizeClients >= 569) {

     $("div.nivoSlider img").each(function() {
         if (endsWith($(this).attr('src'), '_mobile@2x.jpg')) {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\_mobile@2x.jpg/, '') + '.jpg');
         }

    //call div resizer
    resizeDiv();    

     });

     $("div.heroElementWrapper img").each(function() {
         if (endsWith($(this).attr('src'), '_mobile@2x.jpg')) {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\_mobile@2x.jpg/, '') + '.jpg');
         }

    //call div resizer
    resizeDiv();    

     });          

     }      


};

clientsLIControl();

$(window).resize(function() { clientsLIControl(); });
$(window).load(function() { clientsLIControl(); });
$(document).ready(function() { clientsLIControl(); });
```

The HTML is

```
<img id="HeroElementBGImage" title="example" alt="example" src="assets/images/heros/example.jpg">
```

Which then if served on a retina device gets changed to

```
<img id="HeroElementBGImage" title="example" alt="example" src="assets/images/heros/example@2x.jpg">
```